# Segmentation fault with operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, binary-tree

I am creating a binary tree program and I would like to overload a few operators. I have tried overloading the + operator so that when I write something like `myTree + 5`, it would add 5 as a node on the tree.

This is my code:

```
BST myTree;

void operator+(BST left, int right) {
    myTree.addLeaf(right);  
}

int main() {    
    vector<int> treeKeyList;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int before = rand() % 20 + 1;  
    for (int i = 0; i < before; i++) {
        int after = rand() % 20 + 1;
        treeKeyList.push_back(after);
        cout << treeKeyList[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < treeKeyList.size(); i++) {
        myTree + treeKeyList[i];
    }
}
```

At the moment, it seems to run fine through one loop, however it crashes when it tries to add the second value with a segmentation fault error. I think the issue must be in the code I have shown, as before I added the overloading it worked fine. If I did this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < treeKeyList.size(); i++) {
    myTree.addLeaf(treeKeyList[i]);
}
```

It works absolutely fine. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Your overloading is not inuitive becuase operator "+" does not normally mutates it's left hand-side.
2) Even if you think it modifies left hand-side - it actually copies it while passing to function and mutates the copy, so it probably doesn't act like you planned it to,

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/3425536) might help.

Comment: Your operator+ takes its left argument by value, mutates it, and then throws it away. Did you intend to add a node to a temporary copy of your tree, which you can never access?

Comment: Could you post your BST implementation? As the other comments say you've got an "interesting" operator overload, but that in itself shouldn't cause segmentation faults. I wonder if there's something occuring as a result of deleting the left param of your operator

Comment: Looks like you want to overload `+=` instead.

Comment: @zenith Ideally, what I would like to do is to be able to do `tree = tree + 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to take the BST as a reference. Also consider using `+=` instead of `+`.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks! I realised afterwards that I meant to do `tree = tree + 5`, rather than `tree + 5`, but hopefully it won't be too difficult to change.